# Using livesearch textbox twice in a same page

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, ajax

I have used the below code for Livesearch in my webpage and it works fine in the student form. But in the index page for second text box(Staff form), live search is not working. I hope this is due to the use of JQuery function using attribute ID which is same for both input text box. Is there anyway to make the live search work in second text box without changing the entire code?

Thanks in advance

**livesearch.js**

```
$('#college').keyup(function(e)
{   
if ( key != 40 && key != 38 && key != 13 ) livesearch();
}

function livesearch() {
var min_length = 1; // min caracters to display the autocomplete
var keyword = $.trim($('#college').val());
if (keyword.length >= min_length) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'livesearch.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {keyword:keyword},
        success:function(data){
            $('#college_list').show();
            $('#college_list').html(data);
        }   
    });

} else {
    $('#college_list').hide();
}
}
```

**index.php**

```
<div id="student">
     <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="field-wrap">
        <input type="text" id="college"  placeholder="College Name" required 
        autocomplete="off"/>
          <ul id="college_list"></ul>
        </div>
           <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get 
            Started</button>
      </form>   

    <!-- Another Division similar to previous one-->

    <div id="staff">
      <form action="/" method="post">
        <div class="field-wrap">
        <input type="text" id="college"  placeholder="College Name" required 
        autocomplete="off"/>
          <ul id="college_list"></ul>
        </div>
           <button type="submit" class="button button-block"/>Get 
            Started</button>
      </form>
```

**livesearch.php**

```
$parts = explode(' ', $keyword);
    $p = count($parts);

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM colleges WHERE college_id is not null"; 
    for($i = 0; $i < $p; $i++) {
    $sql .= " AND college_name LIKE '%$parts[$i]%'";
    }

    $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':keyword', $keyword, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $list = $query->fetchAll();
    foreach ($list as $rs) {

    // Highlight the written text
    $college_name = highlight($keyword,$rs['college_name']);

    // add new option
    echo '<li onclick="set_item(\''.str_replace("'", "\'", 
    $rs['college_name']).'\')">'.$college_name.'</li>';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting elements with an id - in the first line:

```
$('#college').keyup(function(e) { ... }
```

If you switch that to a class, such as `.live-search` and add this class to your HTML element, the script should naturally work on multiple elements.

ID's in HTML should be unique, whereas classes can be applied to multiple elements.

**Update:** You might also need to switch this line:

`var keyword = $.trim($('#college').val());`

To reference `this` instead:

`var keyword = $.trim($(this).val());`

This will ensure that when you detect a keyup on that element, that the script acts upon that one particular element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I tried your solution but that didn't solved my problem.

Comment: In that case, I would recommend recreating this in jsfiddle or codepen. It's extremely difficult to troubleshoot code with no way to run it.